# Obtener id del usuario recién registrado en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mvc, eloquent

Lo quiero es que luego de registrar al usuario yo pueda obtener el `id` de ese usuario para guardar datos en otra tabla con dicho `id` lo ideal es que sea en el mismo controlador del registro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si emplea el Modelo `User` y crear el usuario directamente con `create` , según la [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserts)

> El método `create` devuelve la instancia de modelo guardado *(nuevo usuario)*:

```
$usuario = User::create([
                'name'=>'UserStack' , 
                'email'=>'user@stack.com',
                'password'=> bcrypt('1234567')]
                );
dd($usuario->id); // Obtenemos el Id que se insertó.
```

Answer (score 0):

Funciono esto era lo que requeria gracias por su ayuda

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $usuario = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'tipo_user' => $data['tipo_user'],
    ]);
    $id_user=$usuario->id;
    $conti="1";
    Empresa::create([
        'nomb_empre' => $data['nombre_empresa'],
        'nit_empre' => $data['cedula'],
        'direccion_empre' => $data['direccion'],
        'fk_id_user' => $id_user,
        'fk_id_continente' => $conti,
        'fk_id_pais' => $data['pais'],
        'fk_id_ciudad' => $data['ciudad'],
    ]);
    return $usuario;
}
```